# $this->class->function(): how does it work?

Tags: php, oop

I've been programming in PHP for several years and I've only just recently begun to look at object oriented code.  Now I understand classes and such:

```
class Myclass {

      public function __construct() {
      }
}
```

and all that good stuff...  I also understand creating functions and calling in my index.php:

```
$someVar = new Myclass;
```

One thing I've been trying to understand, being that i've recently looked at codeigniter and I like one thing about it and want to try and accomplish the same thing without actually using codeigniter.

in code igniter they have the variable $this appear to be their class variable.  But by using that, you're able to call from multiple classes all at once.. such as:

```
$this->load->module(); which is in one class file..
$this->db->query(); which is in another class file.
```

I've searched google for the last few days trying to figure out how to do this same thing where each class would have the correlation between them all allowing me to run $this->class_name->function_name in my projects instead of creating a new variable for each class or for the sake of a clean index file, having every function in a single class file.

Any information (aside from buy this book - as that isn't an option for me) is greatly appreciated and I will thank you now (and will probably thank you again later just for good measure).

Answer (score 0):

The `load` and `db` references are class properties which are themselves other objects with public `module()` and `query()` methods respectively. For example

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var CI_DB
     */
    private $db;

    /**
     * @var Loader
     */
    private $load;

    public function __construct(CI_DB $db, Loader $load)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->load = $load;

        // PHP also allows you to add arbitrary object properties
        // that receive a "public" visibility
        // Please note, this is not a good practice
        $this->foo = new Foo;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $this->load->module();
        $this->db->query();

        // You can also use foo even though it is not defined
        // in the class properties
        $this->foo->something();
    }
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Adding the `foo` property like we did is dangerous. Because it receives the `public` visibility, it may be altered externally to the class.

```
$class = new MyClass($db, $load);
$class->foo = new Bar;
$class->someMethod(); // will break if Bar does not contain a something() method
```

Comment: Okay I can kinda understand that but is not what i'm reading in code...

at least in CI they have a class named CI_Controller  which looks like:

    class CI_Controller {
    public function __constructor() {
$this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');
}
    }

and the Loader is a class...   not a private $load

and $db is actually CI_DB class...

Comment: That's pretty lazy. It's exploiting a *feature* of PHP objects which allows arbitrary property addition without a property declaration. These run-time properties are added with `public` visibility scope. Also, the global function `load_class()` seems very hacky

Comment: oh most definately and I don't need nor do I want a load_class()..  I just need to figure out how to get my parent class in this case Myclass to include and read sub-classes such as My_DB and My_func, then in my index.php be able to call them via $this->db->something or $this->func->something_else

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information. To add properties to your class, I suggest you inject them via the constructor as shown above. FYI, you wouldn't generally use `$this` from your `index.php` file. `$this` only has scope within class methods.

Comment: @Phil so we can conclude that Code Igniter is not teaching best practices.  What's funny to me is the storing of the loaded classes by reference..

Comment: Yeah I know that, and my index.php is also going to be a class file, which extends the parent class in order to use $this in it.. but even if I choose to after the parent class put $someVar = new Myclass; so that all I have to do is require_once or include myclass.php still doesn't explain adding the multiple classes so I can do it while maintaining readability for all files..

include('dbclass.php');
$db = new myDB;

isn't going to be very readable if I get to where I am having to include say 10+ different classes to all be called through $someVar->class_name->class_function

Comment: @tandu and that's why I have come here..  to figure out how to do what I want utilizing best practices, because even though I don't know the scope of OOP like many people, I do know that while codeigniter does some things very well doesn't conform to best practices. Also what's the benefits or detriments of storing loaded classes by reference as apposed to doing it without the ampersand?

I imagine they do it that way because the load_class function is: function &load_class($class, $directory = 'libraries', $prefix = 'CI_') but I could be completely wrong there..

Comment: @Johnny CI is only doing that to be compatible with PHP4. In version 5, all objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @Johnny I really hope, I'm not wrong here, but my point was that all objects are passed by reference, so there's no point in including the ampersand in this case.  It does nothing.

Comment: @Phil and tandu thanks for the info on the ampersand.  That I definitely understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading you and Phil's comments.  First off, you can't use `$this` on `index.php`.  `$this` can only be used in the context of an object.  So you could do,

```
$someVar = new Myclass;
...
$someVar->db->something();
```

...instead.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "read classes," but you can assign members to `MyClass` exactly as Phil indicates:

```
class MyClass {
   private $inj;

   function __construct(Injected $inj) {
      $this->injected = $inj;
   }
}
```

Note that the `private $inj` declaration is not mandatory, but skipping it is dangerous.  Any non-declared members added are automatically `public`, and this can potentially screw with you if you rely on magical get.  I would declare the properties you need.

Finally, you either need to include all class definitions you will use, use a function like `load_class()`, or [use autoloading](http://us.php.net/autoload).  If `Injected` above is not a declared class, you will get an error when trying to create one.  `load_class()` almost certainly includes the class definition somehow.

Comment: If `index.php` is included within a class method, it may use `$this` but I doubt this matches the OP's situation

Comment: index.php would ideally be a class in and of itself that extends the parent class..  

I do like the idea of doing Injected $inj and private $inj..  however if i get to the point im running 10+ and perhaps upwards of 20 different classes, adding all of those in the __construct would get really ugly...  So while I could use a load_class function (and i will probably have to make something in order to do it)...  But how to get it to follow best practices is the question..  and still the $this-> in my index.php (which would be a class in this case)